# SQL group by not equal results

Tags: sql, t-sql, postgresql

I am using postgres but I know T-SQL too so any answer anyone can give me ill be grateful and able to make the conversion. I am trying to run a query for my company that's a car sales company. they sell cars all over the US primarily in OR and WA. I need to come up with a report that will allow me to return sales that are new for OR and new for Wa and then the problem I'm having is the sales for all the other states that are not OR or Wa. So right now im running a union with group by where one query is for WA and the other statement is for OR. I want the results to look really simple and just have 3 rows. 1 OR 1 WA and the 3rd row all the other states combined. I cant figure out how to combine the not equal to OR or WA into one single value. Is this even possible?

Thank you for taking the time to look at this

my query will also include used sale cars but I can integrate that once I figure out how to get this problem figured out so that's why the query has multiple unions

Here's my query I have now:

```
SELECT buyerstate        AS "State", 
       Count(buyerstate) AS "Acura", 
       saletype          AS "N/U" 
FROM   lydeal 
WHERE  stocklocationid = '8' 
       AND buyerstate = 'OR' 
       AND saledate > '8/01/12' 
       AND saletype = 'N' 
GROUP  BY buyerstate, 
          stocklocationid, 
          saletype 
UNION 
SELECT buyerstate        AS "State", 
       Count(buyerstate) AS "Acura", 
       saletype          AS "N/U" 
FROM   lydeal 
WHERE  stocklocationid = '8' 
       AND buyerstate = 'OR' 
       AND saledate > '8/01/12' 
       AND saletype = 'U' 
GROUP  BY buyerstate, 
          stocklocationid, 
          saletype 
UNION 
SELECT buyerstate        AS "State", 
       Count(buyerstate) AS "Acura", 
       saletype          AS "N/U" 
FROM   lydeal 
WHERE  stocklocationid = '8' 
       AND buyerstate = 'WA' 
       AND saledate > '8/01/12' 
       AND saletype = 'N' 
GROUP  BY buyerstate, 
          stocklocationid, 
          saletype 
UNION 
SELECT buyerstate        AS "State", 
       Count(buyerstate) AS "Acura", 
       saletype          AS "N/U" 
FROM   lydeal 
WHERE  stocklocationid = '8' 
       AND buyerstate = 'WA' 
       AND saledate > '8/01/12' 
       AND saletype = 'U' 
GROUP  BY buyerstate, 
          stocklocationid, 
          saletype
```

Comment: thx for editing this for me so its more readable

Comment: So you need OR, WA, then All other states combined or would you just not want any other states in the mix at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN buyerstate IN ('OR','Wa') THEN buyerstate ELSE 'OTHER' END   AS "State", 
   Count(buyerstate) AS "Acura", 
   saletype          AS "N/U" 
FROM   lydeal 
WHERE  stocklocationid = '8' 
   AND saledate > '8/01/12' 
   AND saletype = 'N' 
GROUP  BY CASE WHEN buyerstate IN ('OR','Wa') THEN buyerstate ELSE 'OTHER' END, 
      stocklocationid, 
      saletype
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN buyerstate IN ('OR', 'WA')
            THEN buyerstate
            ELSE 'other'
        END AS OR_or_WA_or_other,
       ...
  FROM lydeal
 WHERE ...
 GROUP
    BY CASE WHEN buyerstate IN ('OR', 'WA')
            THEN buyerstate
            ELSE 'other'
        END,
       ...
 ORDER
    BY OR_or_WA_or_other
;
```

(You can actually change `OR_or_WA_or_other` to `buyerstate`, but I figured it was clearer to use a new name, so it's clear which places are referring to what.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do something like this:

```
SELECT buyerstate        AS "State", 
       Count(buyerstate) AS "Acura",
       saletype          AS "N/U" 
FROM   lydeal 
WHERE  stocklocationid = '8' 
       AND (
          (buyerstate in ('OR', 'WA') AND saledate > '8/01/12' AND saletype in ('N', 'U')) OR //Only new sales for Or and Wa
          (buyerstate not in ('OR', 'WA')) //all other sales
       )
       AND saletype = 'N' 
GROUP  BY buyerstate, 
          stocklocationid, 
          saletype
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
select buyerstate as "State",count(buyerstate) as "Acura", saletype as "N/U"
from lydeal
where stocklocationid = '8' and buyerstate = 'OR' and saledate > '8/01/12' and saletype = 'N'
group by buyerstate,stocklocationid,saletype
union

select buyerstate as "State",count(buyerstate) as "Acura", saletype as "N/U"
from lydeal
where stocklocationid = '8' and buyerstate = 'WA' and saledate > '8/01/12' and saletype = 'N'
group by buyerstate,stocklocationid,saletype

union
select 'Others' as "State",count(buyerstate) as "Acura", saletype as "N/U"
from lydeal
where stocklocationid = '8' and buyerstate <> 'WA' and buyerstate <> 'OR'  and saledate > '8/01/12' and saletype = 'N'
group by stocklocationid,saletype
```

For the third part just use something instead of buyerstate and do not make a group by on it, and it should help.